# Integer Partition into Powers

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, integer-partitions

Is there any way to count the number of integer partitions of a number $N$ into powers of two such that each size is repeated a power of two times?

Ok, so the recurrence can be expressed by:

$a(0)=1$, $a(2n+1)=a(n)$, $a(2n) = a(n)+a(n-1)+\ldots+a(n-2^m)+\ldots$ $= a(n)+\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\log_{2} n\rfloor}a(n-2^i)$

Is there any asymptotic upper bound on this recurrence?

Many Thanks

Comment: This is OEIS sequence A086449: https://oeis.org/A086449

Comment: can you please elaborate more

Comment: I'm guessing from what's at the OEIS link that there's no closed form that allows you to compute a value directly, but for not-too-large $N$, you can count these partitions by hand or with some computational help. Here is a Mathematica expression to tabulate the values for $N$ up to $100$: Table[Count[
  Complement[#, 2^Range[0, 10]] &@#[[All, 2]] & /@ 
   Tally /@ IntegerPartitions[n, All, 2^Range[0, 10]], {}], {n, 1, 
  100}]

Comment: I want a polynomial bound on this sequence? Do you think that this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a relatively easy bound: let $b(n) = \max_{i\leq n }a(i)$.  Then we should have $b(2n)\leq \lceil \lg n\rceil b(n)$, so $b(2^k)\leq kb(2^{k-1})$ and $b(2^k)\in O(k!)\in O(k^k) = O(2^{k\lg k})$.  This gives a bound of $O(n^{\lg\lg n})$; at first glance it's not clear that this can be improved all the way to a polynomial bound.

Comment: I am aware of this bound. Moreover I can attain it in a different way. Namely we can describe a partition of these partitions in log(n)loglog(n) bits so there number cannot exceed O(n^(lglgn)). However I am wondering if a polynomial bound exist.

Comment: @kyloc my gut instinct says no; I don't know of any specific argument, but I would be looking for information-theoretic rationales.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd also guess $O(n^{\lg \lg n})$ is as good as you can do, but it's just a guess. You could try posting a new question with a title like “Does the OEIS sequence A086449 have a polynomial bound?” with the same tags as this question.

Comment: @SteveKass I largely agree with that, though I'dsuggest revising this question, retitling it and editing it a bit to essentially be that one.  ('OEIS sequence A086449 is defined by ... and represents ...; what are the best bounds known for it?')

Comment: Thanks I will ask a new question